# FetchRequest returning duplicate results on subsequent executions

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data

I have the following code set up on a second tab of a tabbarcontroller.  The first time I come into the tab, my data is fetched properly, as expected.  However, if I leave the tab, and come back, the `array` returned by the fetch request contains double the entries.  Each object it returns is duplicated.  If I leave the tab and come back again, then the entries get duplicated again, giving me 3 of each.  What am I doing wrong with my request that would make this happen?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // sort the results, since we want the most recent entry first
    NSSortDescriptor *dateSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"key" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateSort];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *array = [[delegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    self.fetchedObjects = [array copy];
    [array removeAllObjects];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**Update:** I switched to NSFetchedResultsController and this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to NSFetchedResultsController and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing immediately shows why that would happen, but the questionable coding surrounding the actual fetch itself indicates that there may be some errors in your delegate methods or other parts of the controller.

Are you also using a fetched results controller?  Are you changing the fetchObjects collection later on?

Does the database actually contain all those extra objects, or is it just the array in this controller?

Also, note that doing all this work in viewWillAppear is probably not a good choice.

Comment: No, I'm not using a fetched results controller. I'm not changing the collection, just displaying it in a table view. The data can be added to from another tab though, which is why I re-fetch in in viewWillAppear.  The database doesn't contain the extra objects, just the array on subsequent calls.

Comment: You should put a breakpoint at every method in this controller, and see where the count in the array changes.  Do you happen to have a custom implementation of setFetchedAttributes?

Comment: The count is doubled right as the fetch is executed. If I check array before and after the fetch I can see the duplicated entries.  On the first execution it returns the correct amount.  And no, I do not have a custom implementation.

Comment: What count are you talking about?  Sorry, but if you want further help, you will need to provide more/better information... like a log trace, or debugger stack trace of code where this exactly happens... otherwise it's guessing in the dark.  The only strange thing I see in what you posted is that awkward mutable/copy/remove dance.  It's useless, and confusing.

Comment: Sorry...  that comment came out sounding rude.  I didn't mean it that way.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try changing your code to `self.fetchedObjects = [[delegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];`

Could you also show us more code including the implemented `UITableViewDataSource` & `UITableViewDelegate methods`?